# How to preload route using react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using a TabNavigator and I would like to preload all of the routes so that the user does not experience any lagging when he navigates for the first time to one of the tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to add `lazy: false` into routes options

Comment: I've added it on `createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>().Navigator` and this doesn't help, I have `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Search"} was not handled by any navigator.`